# Can I use the .apply(lambda function to return values based on condition while skipping for values where condition is not met?

Tags: pandas

[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/259Y6.jpg)Data:

```
    cuisine  violations
0    Afghan          19
1   African          99
2  Armenian       10799
3  Armenian          37
4     Asian         518
```

My data set is cuisine types and I want to create a condition where I rename the cuisine type 'other' if the associated violation count is less than 1000, I am looking to assign them as 'other' so that my pie chart is cleaner.

I tried using the following which doesn't skip cuisine type if the condition is False, as i would have expected.

```
Manhattan_groupby['cuisine'] = Manhattan_groupby['violations'].apply(lambda x: 'other' if (x <= 1000) else None)
```

Manhattan_groupby

Comment: Sorry - groupby is actually part of the variable name, so we're not performing groupby function.

Comment: I am not looking to exclude the rows more than 1000, I would like to keep them as is. I want to change the cuisine value to 'other' if the violation value is less than 1000 because I am deeming them as statistically irrelevant in the study.

Comment: I agree, but if you're going to label them as 'other' and then likely filter them out later,  why go through the middle step? Just filter `df[df.violations.lt(1000)]` before any analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manhattan_groupby['cuisine'] = np.where(Manhattan_groupby['violations'] < 1000, 'other', Manhattan_groupby['cuisine'])
```

you can use np.where to complete if statements like this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `loc` and Boolean indexing:

```
Manhattan_groupby.loc[Manhattan_groupby['violations'] < 1000, 'cuisine'] = 'other'
```

Comment: That was helpful, and had not seen df[df.violations.lt(1000)] usage before. thank YOU!